# Is it possible to connect biometric device through modem to connect to an APN using GSM?

Tags: c#, gsm, fingerprint, gprs, biometrics

I am using zketco gsm/gprs biometric device.I tried to connect through gsm using this Zkemkeeper.dll .It works fine for tcp/ip network protocol.I am using following code for connect tcp/ip protocol.

Is it possible to connect through gsm?.

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IsConnected = zkemKeeper.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, 4370);
                if (IsConnected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Device Connected Successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    zkemKeeper.GetLastError(ref ErrorCode);
                    MessageBox.Show("Device Not Found. Error Code : " + ErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest question has been already posted in stackoverflow. The question is: [Is it possible to connect biometrics zkemkeeper using gsm in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596547/is-it-possible-to-connect-biometrics-zkemkeeper-using-gsm-in-c/)

The following answer posted there, applies here too.

> zkemkeeper C# SDK library is provided to develop the desktop application. You should have the devices connected to the application through TCP/IP. For connecting the gsm devices from a remote location to your .Net application, you need to go for the web api support. Refer the api documentation at http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html