# Is it possible to connect biometrics zkemkeeper using gsm in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fingerprint, biometrics

I am new to biometric device but i connect biometric device using lan networks. It works fine but one of our clients need data from multiple locations. We give them gsm and dyndns server. Now i want to connect with my application using c# asp.net.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite not possible using asp.net.

There are ways to do that but it may or may not involve asp.net. You might just in case need an alternate approach.

These are the three techniques that might help you :

**Using the Push SDK**

Zkteco devices have their own feature to export data to remote databases (MsSQL, Postgres etc) using the ADMS feature. (Do some research on the ADMS feature and how it works)

Softwares like the [Zkteco Biotime](http://www.zkteco.me/product-details/biotime-70) make use of that feature to handle data from multiple devices distributed in multiple locations. Do take a look at how the Biotime handles it using their online [demo software](http://80.227.52.78:8080/accounts/login/).

*The default username, password should be **admin** for the demo software.*

There are different varieties of Zkteco SDK. The one which you will be needing is the **Push Sdk**. But I think they have stopped distributing that SDK.

Go through the PDF file in [this link](https://studylib.net/doc/5272361/sdk---zkteco) to know more about the types of SDK.

**Using Port Forwarding**

This is an alternate approach but not quite secure as you will be making the device publicly available.

Basically you just add up the device port number (**4370**) to your routes configuration and access the device via a public IP.

[Here is a video link related to Zkteco device port forwarding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaX_UT09DAI)

**Using a windows service**

This approach will require you to write a windows service that will be installed in each location where ever you wish to grab the attendance records from.

The windows service will have a simple task of grabbing attendance data from the devices in its network and exporting all those data to a common portal (A Central database or API).

If you are new to biometric devices, Go through [my article in Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started) to get started.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify one thing on @Ozesh post:
 
_There are different varieties of Zkteco SDK. The one which you will be needing is the Push Sdk. But I think they have stopped distributing that SDK._

They still distribute the PushSDK, but now it´s licensed... You have to pay for enabling it on the device.

Answer (score 0):

zkemkeeper C# SDK library is provided to develop the desktop application. You should have the devices connected to the application through TCP/IP. For connecting the gsm devices from remote location to your .Net application, you need to go for the web api support. Refer the api documentation at http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html